# svn blame without author and version number info

Tags: svn

I want to see who is responsible for some code and in which version, could use `svn blame` to accomplish this, e.g.

```
svn blame com/foo/web/action/order/CustomerCreateOrderAction.java | grep 'queryArtisanCond.setSelectOnlyId(true);'
7943  wenshuang         queryArtisanCond.setSelectOnlyId(true);
```

it's ok, but sometimes I found below output no version number and author, e.g.

```
svn blame com/foo/web/action/order/CustomerCreateOrderAction.java | grep 'ArtisanConstant.ARTISAN_DATEVERSION_NEW'        
 -          -                 if (ArtisanConstant.ARTISAN_DATEVERSION_NEW.equals(artisanVo.getDateVersion())) {
```

So why is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if the file has local modifications that were not yet committed or if there were commits but no call to `svn up` since then.

Comment: maybe you're right I tried to specify version number(current version number - 1) , this time could have author and version number info, e.g `svn blame -r 19880 com/foo/web/action/order/CustomerCreateOrderAction.java | grep 'ArtisanConstant.ARTISAN_DATEVERSION_NEW'`   but why in the same file some code could have author and version number info , some code not?

Comment: @zhuguowei because only *modified* lines are marked as `- -`. Svn detects those lines that are unchanged and shows the corresponding `blame` information for them, even if other lines have modifications.